# Turtle stops when I shoot

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have gotten an issue where an enemy turtle stops when I shoot. I am relatively new to python so I know that my code is pretty bad. I cant seem to spot why this happens but I'm assuming its got something to do with the while loop.

here is the code:
(i have added notes so it is easy to skip to important parts of it)

```
import turtle
import os
#wn is window
#bp = border
bullet = 'ready'
#screen setup
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.title('SPACE.INVADERS')


#border
bp = turtle.Turtle()
bp.speed(0)
bp.color('green')
bp.penup()
bp.setposition(-300,-300)
bp.pendown()
count=0
while count != 5:
    count= (count+1)
    bp.fd(600)
    bp.lt(90)
bp.hideturtle()

#player
p = turtle.Turtle()
p.color('red')
p.shape('triangle')
p.penup()
p.speed(0)
p.setposition(0,-250)
p.setheading(90)

#enemy
e = turtle.Turtle()
e.penup()
e.speed(0)
e.shape('square')
e.shapesize(1.25,1.25)
e.color('orange')
e.setpos(-250,250)
e.speed(1)





#p = player
#ps = player speed

ps = 15

#moving left and right
def left_mov():
    x = p.xcor()
    x -= ps
    p.setx(x)

def right_mov():
    x = p.xcor()
    x += ps
    p.setx(x)
#shooting
def shoot():
    global bullet
    if bullet == 'ready':
        bullet = 'fire'
        shot= turtle.Turtle()
        shot.penup()
        shot.speed(0)
        shot.goto(p.pos())
        shot.color('white')
        shot.shape('triangle')
        shot.shapesize(0.5)
        shot.lt(90)
        shot.speed(1)
        shot.fd(550)
        bullet = 'ready'




#bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(left_mov, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(right_mov, 'Right')
turtle.onkey(shoot, 'space')
#enemy movement
while True:
    e.fd(500)
    e.rt(90)
    e.fd(25)
    e.rt(90)
    e.fd(500)
    e.lt(90)
    e.fd(25)
    e.lt(90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm assuming its got something to do with the while loop

Yes, it shouldn't be there!  In an event-driven world like turtle, there should never be a `while True:` loop.  Instead, we need a timer event that fires off on regular intervals that does incremental updates of the objects in motion (enemy and bullet) so they appear to move at the same time.  Below is my rework of your code using a timer event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# moving left and right
def left_move():
    player.setx(player.xcor() - player_speed)

def right_move():
    player.setx(player.xcor() + player_speed)

# screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('SPACE.INVADERS')

# border
border = Turtle(visible=False)
border.speed('fastest')
border.color('green')

border.penup()
border.setposition(-300, -300)
border.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    border.forward(600)
    border.left(90)

# player
player = Turtle('triangle')
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('red')

player.penup()
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)

player_speed = 15

# enemy
enemy = Turtle('square')
enemy.speed('fast')
enemy.shapesize(1.25)
enemy.color('orange')
enemy.penup()

enemy.setpos(-250, 250)

enemy_speed = 6  # enemy speed
enemy_direction = 1  # enemy direction

# bullet
bullet = Turtle('triangle', visible=False)
bullet.speed('fastest')
bullet.color('white')
bullet.shapesize(0.5)
bullet.penup()
bullet.left(90)

bullet_speed = 9  # bullet speed

# shooting

def shoot():
    if not bullet.isvisible():
        bullet.goto(player.position())
        bullet.showturtle()

def move():
    global enemy_direction

    if bullet.isvisible():
        if bullet.ycor() > 275:
            bullet.hideturtle()
        else:
            bullet.forward(bullet_speed)

    # enemy movement

    enemy.forward(enemy_direction * enemy_speed)
    enemy.settiltangle(enemy.tiltangle() + 3)  # just for fun

    x, y = enemy.position()

    if x > 250 or x < -250:
        enemy_direction *= -1
        enemy.sety(y - 25)

    screen.ontimer(move, 50)

# bindings
screen.onkey(left_move, 'Left')
screen.onkey(right_move, 'Right')
screen.onkey(shoot, 'space')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

This should give you the basic functionality you need to move forward and add collision detection (bullet to enemy, enemy to player, player to wall) and scoring.

Also note that turtles are global entities so creating a new bullet every time you need one is a bad idea.  Even if you evenually allow overlapping bullets, keep a reusable set of bullets for that purpose.